# org.hibernate.MappingException - What does this exception mean?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Ruleset, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ruleset)]
```

class snippet:

```
@Entity
public class Ruleset implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@OneToOne(targetEntity = RulesetStatus.class)
private Integer id;

private Set<Rule> ruleset = new HashSet<Rule>(0);

public Ruleset() {
}


public Ruleset(Integer ID, Set<Rule> ruleset) {
    this.id = ID;
    this.ruleset = ruleset;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Set<Rule> getRuleSet(){
   return this.ruleset;        
}

public void setRuleset(Set<Rule> ruleset) {
    this.ruleset = ruleset;
}

}
```

I've figured out that annotating ruleset as Transient makes the problem go away, but then ruleset won't be persisted to the DB. How do I tell hibernate about the type of this field?

I'm very new to Hibernate so I'm totally lost here.
__________________________Edit__________________________
The actual relationship should have been @ManyToMany as a rule can be in many rulesets and a ruleset can have many rules.

I added the @ManyToMany annotation to the set, then did not have a corresponding set in the Rule Class to map to. I added the set in the rule class, added the @ManyToMany annotation to that, and no I have no errors.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: You miss the @ManyToOne annotation on ruleset?

Comment: Meaby here you have your answer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/es-ES/html/collections.html or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqvn/index.html

Comment: You should also post the relevant portions of your db schema.

Comment: Yes, the basic modeling makes sence. As I stated in my answer, it is possible to fine tune the annotations. I am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all fields (or properties) are mapped in JPA. That's why you have to tell the JPA provider what your `Set` is supposed to map (one-to-many, many-to-many, `@ElementCollection`, etc.), or map it as `@Transient` to tell the provider that you don't want the property to be persisted.